# How to stop entry in GREENPLUM log_alert_* tables?

Tags: greenplum

I am using Pivotal Greenplum sandbox.

Want to stop entry into log_alert_* tables? Which are under gpperfmon database.

Is, there is a way to stop it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable gpperfmon

```
gpconfig -c gp_enable_gpperfmon -v off
gpstop -arf
```